# MS Teams Message Extension always firing after installation

Tags: microsoft-teams

In building an MS Teams app with Message Extensions (I need a "task" modal for my iframe content), I cannot seem to prevent the "task" modal from firing immediately after installation.

I've tried ignoring the inbound request, yet still - an empty modal is present.

How might I circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is solved by adding a "personal tab" to your application. Who knew?